# Need Guidance Building and Using oauth Jar

Tags: maven, jar, build

I have various projects in which I need to authenticate using oauth, so I downloaded oauth2 from here: http://supergsego.com/apache/oltu/org.apache.oltu.oauth2/

I simplistically assumed that in order to use oauth2, I need to create a jar file with the functionality and include it on the class path for my projects. 
I'm a complete maven beginner, but I built the project by changing to the directory with `pom.xml` and issued the command `mvn package`.

That created a directory called `target` with a jar file called `org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-1.0.0.jar` and a number of subdirectories, each with their own jar file.

My question is: Do I need include only `org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-1.0.0.jar` on my class path, or does `org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client-1.0.0.jar` have dependencies on the jars in the sub-directories, thereby requiring that I include those jar files too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the parent dependency:

```
<oltu.oauth2.version>1.0.1</oltu.oauth2.version>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.parent</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

but it didn't work coz it couldn't find the jar file on the maven repo.  So I tried adding the dependencies for each individual module:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.httpclient4</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.dynamicreg.client</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.dynamicreg.common</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.authzserver</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.resourceserver</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.resourceserver-filter</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.dynamicreg.server</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.oltu.oauth2.jwt</artifactId>
    <version>${oltu.oauth2.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and voila! it worked!  Just comment out a module that you don't need to trim down your dependency list.